# how to use a predefined integer value in spim

Tags: spim

I have written this section of code but have hit a problem:

line 37 column 5: "x": operand is of incorrect type

but I have declared it and called it correctly, have I not,? just the same as with the .ascizz data stored at `$t1 and $t2` I know that both the programs work as I can run them separate it the just the condition I have placed on line 37 which is some what wrong.

I believe whe problem could be error  on the first line of section # third number when li x, 5 5 is used. I believe it's the wrong method of calling the variable x.

I'm new to this and it's probably a simple fix but once I have mastered this i can set any amount of variables i.e x,y,z. Assign numbers to them and apply condition.that's my desired outcome of this little exercise.

```
 .data
prompt1: .asciiz "\n\n Enter firs integer please: "
prompt2: .asciiz "Enter second integer please: "
result:  .asciiz "The result is:"
x: .word 60
array1: .space  12      #  declare 12 bytes of storage to hold array of 3 integers

.text

main:
    #t0 - to hold first integer
    #t1 - to hold secon integer
    #t2 - to hold sum of $t1 and $t0

    # first number

    li $v0, 4           # system call to print string asking for input
    la $a0, prompt1     # address of string to print
    syscall

    li $v0, 5           # system call to read integer
    syscall
    move $t0, $v0       # move the read number stored in $v0 into $t0

    #second number
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt2
    syscall

    li $v0, 5
    syscall

    move $t1, $v0
    #thir number

    li x, 5
    syscall
    move $t3, $v0
    add $t2,$0,$0

    add $t2, $t1, $t0   # add contents of $t0 and $t1 and store in $t2
    bge st2, $t3, end     # Branch to Label if st2 ≥ x (signed)

    # print out contents of $t2


    li $2,1             # $v0<-service#1 (print int)
    move $4, $t2        # $a0<-$8, move result to $a0
    syscall             # call to system service

    li $v0, 10          #syscall to exit
    syscall 

    end:
    la  $t0, array1 #  load base address of array into register $t0
    li  $t1, 5      #  $t1 = 5   ("load immediate")
    sw  $t1, ($t0)  #  first array element set to 5; indirect addressing
    li  $t1, 13     #   $t1 = 13
    sw  $t1, 4($t0) #  second array element set to 13
    li  $t1, -7     #   $t1 = -7
    sw  $t1, 8($t0) #  third array element set to -7
    li  $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t2
    syscall
```

Answer (score 0):

The `li` pseudo-instruction places an immediate value into a register.  You can't use it to move data into memory.  If you want to place data at location `x`, you need to first store the immediate value in a register, then use `sw`.